# Netty 3.5.8-Final - Help on FrameDecoder

Tags: exception, netty, decoder

I have the following code for my framedecoder:

```
protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext,
        Channel channel, ChannelBuffer channelBuffer) throws Exception {

    //Header 1 + 4 length bytes
    if (channelBuffer.readableBytes() < 5) {
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println(channelBuffer.readerIndex());

    //mark the reader index
    channelBuffer.markReaderIndex();

    //extract the length bytes and convert to an int value 
    //**note: length value of the message is a decimal not hex
    StringBuilder lengthBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int ctr = 1; ctr < 5; ctr += 1) {
        lengthBuilder.append(String.format("%02x",
                channelBuffer.getByte(ctr)));
    }
    int length = Integer.parseInt(hexToASCII(lengthBuilder.toString()));
    System.out.println("This is the length: " + length);
    System.out.println("reader index: " + channelBuffer.readerIndex());
            channelBuffer.readerIndex(4);

    //get the remaining bytes
    if (channelBuffer.readableBytes() <= length) {
        channelBuffer.resetReaderIndex();
        return null;
    }

    String s = "";
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < length + 5; ctr += 1) {
        s += (char) channelBuffer.getByte(ctr);
    }

    return s;
}
```

everything's going fine until the `int length = Integer.parseInt(hexToASCII(lengthBuilder.toString()));` line. After that line, the decoder can still read the remaining bytes but it is now using the actual message as the length field generating a parse exception error.

Say, i have a message `B0005EHELLO` where `[B is the header] [0005 - actual message length] [E - header 2] [HELLO - actual message]`.. After parsing the length field to an integer value, the decoder uses the first four letters of the actual message `HELL` to parse the length field and an exception was being produced. Kindly help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the readerIndex from 4 to 5.

`channelBuffer.readerIndex(4);`

I also added a reader index reset before returning the result so that it would read the whole message not just the actual message :)

```
channelBuffer.readerIndex(0);
String s = "";
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < length + 5; ctr += 1) {
    s += (char) channelBuffer.getByte(ctr);
}
```